# What is the difference between writing sql join on together and separately?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

My question is what's the difference between

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b
LEFT JOIN table_c c
ON a.id = b.id and a.name = c.name
```

and

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table_a a join table_b b on a.id=b.id
left join table_c on a.name = c.name
```

Comment: Does the first version actually run?  If so, are the results set the same?

Comment: Could you share the data you've used for this test yourself, as well as the output you're seeing firsthand?

Comment: I don't think the first query will actually work. `Join` without `on` or `using` will return a syntax error.

Comment: The queries are legal in MySQL (except a typo - an alias for `table_c` in 2nd query is lost).

Comment: @t.peter A JOIN without an ON or USING is fine

Comment: @Strawberry . . . That is another case of MySQL allowing non-standard (and broken IMHO) syntax.   The first query is not standard and should fail because of a missing `ON` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well it saves typing 'CROSS' at least!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_a (id INT, name INT) 
> SELECT 1 id, 1 name UNION SELECT 2,2 UNION SELECT 4,4;
> CREATE TABLE table_b (id INT) 
> SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3;
> CREATE TABLE table_c (name INT) 
> SELECT 1 name UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM table_a a
> JOIN table_b b
> LEFT JOIN table_c c
> ON a.id = b.id and a.name = c.name
> ```
>
> ```
> a.id | a.name | b.id | c.name
> -:   | ---:   | -:   | ---:
>  4   |    4   |  1   | null
>  2   |    2   |  1   | null
>  1   |    1   |  1   |    1
>  4   |    4   |  2   | null
>  2   |    2   |  2   | null
>  1   |    1   |  2   | null
>  4   |    4   |  3   | null
>  2   |    2   |  3   | null
>  1   |    1   |  3   | null
> ```

All pairs from rows of first two tables are generated (JOIN without ON acts as CROSS JOIN), then third table is joined to matched pairs only.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM table_a a join table_b b on a.id=b.id
> left join table_c c on a.name = c.name
> ```
>
> ```
> a.id | a.name | b.id | c.name
> -:   | ---:   | -:   | ---:
>  1   |    1   |  1   |    1
>  2   |    2   |  2   | null
> ```

Only matched pairs from rows of first two tables are generated, then third table is joined to matched pairs.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a84e9292bc2eb53d841dde8034f05556)*